# Does anybody knows the way to access Disk IO queue length in Java?

Tags: java, io, disk

Does anybody knows the way to access Disk IO queue length in Java?
Open Source, native library , anything?
Important issue is to handle any kind of disk,any kind of OS, or at least any kind of Linux..

Comment: Is this just for interest or is there a reason you need to know this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sar -dp  on linux should give you the queue length

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in pure Java.

In fact, I don't know if there is a way to find this out using native code and system calls.  (I don't recall any Linux utilities that tell you the IO queue lengths ... and if the utilities can't do it, I can't see how anything else could.)

Comment: strange...but there is a PerfMonitor, which show the Queue lenght at least in windows, so it is possible to do at least in native libs....

Comment: @Alexey I don't believe there is equivilent tool in Unix.  Normally if you need something written to disk, you have to wait for it to be written e.g. MappedByteBuffer.force().

Comment: just found something for Linux, which is not reporting Disk Queue but reporting Disk Time response.You need to install IOTOP and parse in in Java...anyway many thanks for help and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is  [Java 7 (NIO.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) have a method inside for you?

Comment: I dont think so..didnt found anything..it mostly deals with files I/O , not with Disk Analytic, but of course maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Allright, I had not clearly understood. Perhaps you can use the OS commands with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html